# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0 with Minecraft Forge 1.12.2

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I'm trying to program some mods for Minecraft 1.12.2 using Forge. When I run :runClient i get this error:

> Task :runClient FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':runClient'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
> Could not find net.minecraftforge:forge:1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.pom
> - https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar
> - file:/C:/Users/Marek/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.pom
> - file:/C:/Users/Marek/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/bundeled_repo/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar
> - https://libraries.minecraft.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 16s
8 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 4 up-to-date

Please help quick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what happened - I had JDK 14 and Minecraft needs JDK 1.8