# Failed to create instance of tooling API whilst trying to import Grade project to Eclipse 2021-09

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

I wanted to start creating mods for Minecraft 1.12.2 by following this [tutorial](https://codakid.com/guide-to-minecraft-modding-with-java/). So I downloaded the [Forge mdk for MC 1.12.2](https://files.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.12.2.html), extraced the zip file and copied the contents to a separate folder. Then I launched Eclipse and clicked on import project, chose existing Gradle project, specified the location of the folder and clicked Finish. But then this error popped up:

> Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-bin.zip'.

I have a Windows 10 machine and installed [this](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot) JDK as I was told to do so in the tutorial. Tho when I installed eclipse the JKD 16 was selected by default as VM and as you can see in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQIFk.jpg) screenshot below the installed didn't let me choose JDK 8. I don't know if that might be the issue nor how to fix it. Maybe I'd have to use Eclipse 2020, but I'd prefer not to.

Now I looked at the gradle linke and found that changing the version might fix the problem. But then why would forge itself have a non working link in their gradle project. And if that's the issue I have no clue which gradle version to use.

Ressources I read but didn't help:

1. [Eclipse/Minecraft error when importing gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506535/eclipse-minecraft-error-when-importing-gradle) --> I deleted the folder and it didn't let me start eclipse again. With [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fruMX.jpg) message
2. [Trying to mod MC Forge 1.12.2, but SetupDecompWorkspace not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461573/trying-to-mod-mc-forge-1-12-2-but-setupdecompworkspace-not-working) --> Errors while running the commands.
3. [Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0 with Minecraft Forge 1.12.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613713/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with) --> Issue seems unrelated but solution is a bit what I excpected my solution to be like. Tho no explanation on how to solve it.

Comment: Eclipse, itself, needs at least Java 11 to run, but you can use other versions of Java to run programs from inside Eclipse. In the Eclipse Preferences use "Java > Installed JREs' to tell Eclipse about other Java versions. You can choose which Java to use in the Project Properties and the Run Configuration.

Comment: @greg-449 Ok I managed to "tell Eclipse" about the other java version but the error still doesn't go away when importing the gradle project.